# Receiving data from backend returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In the node.js in the login post endpoint, I get the login data for user. I declare `req.user.dataValues` in variable `userData` and I'm trying to access it inside `/data` endpoint so later I can access it on frontend.

Node.js - localhost:4000

```js
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
          return next(err)
      } else if (!user) { 
          console.log('message: ' + info.message);
          return res.redirect('/login') 
      } else {
          req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              return next(err);
            }

            let userData = req.user.dataValues;
            router.get('/data', (req, res) => {
              console.log(userData)
              res.json({user: userData})
            })
            

            res.json({ redirectUrl: "app", user: req.user.dataValues});
          });
      }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

I'm using the code below to fetch the data from the `/data` endpoint from node.js. I don't get any errors but the result is undefined, I wonder why? I need this data in my frontend to build the login etc.

react.js - localhost:3000

```js
    Testing = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:4000/data")
        .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result)
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Have you allowed Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) by adding appropriate header(s)?

Comment: Also you are returning error via `next(err)` but you don't seem to be handling it somewhere

Comment: This is my CORS settings ```app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.use(cors)
```

I'm not sure about `next(err)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran some test on express. Looks like you are defining your `/data` endpoint the wrong way.

You are defining the endpoint inside an anonymous function hence it exists only inside the scope of the function.

You should move

```
router.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(userData)
    res.json({user: userData})
})
```

outside the `router.post('/login)`

Comment: Another possibility could be because you are using the name `res` for both variables of `\login` and `\data` endpoint, you are not actually sending response to the original request.

Comment: I've thought about this but the user data is inside `/login` POST endpoint. And I can't access that data in the `/data`. I mean I don't know a way to do that.

Comment: Use sessions in passport. You can get an idea from here http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

When login is successful, store the data in session and respond with a 200 status code or redirect.
When /data is requested, look for stored value in session if it exists, return the same.

Comment: I'm using the `serializeUser` function inside `/login` POST and `deserializeUser` function inside `/data` endpoint. But doesn't work. Do you mind giving me code example or something? Would help a lot!

Comment: serializing and deserializing will not store in session rather make your data usable for storing in sessions. What you should actually use is a session middleware in express. You can follow [this](https://youtu.be/6FOq4cUdH8k) tutorial or follow the github repo linked in description.

Comment: In short you need to do these steps

1. Install and setup [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

2. Use `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` middlewares